# Whose death is being avenged in Avengers: Infinity War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, avengers-infinity-war

#### Here be spoilers!

I was under the impression, given the name, that the team of Avengers are avenging the death of one of the team (sometimes it's the extended team). So in A:IW, who is being avenged?

> The reason I ask is ... so many die.

Edit:

The [IMDB trivia page for The Avengers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/trivia) says, "Agent Phil Coulson... is killed off in the middle of the film, giving the Avengers someone to avenge."

The [IMDB trivia page for Avengers: Age of Ultron](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2395427/trivia) says, "For the first time, a major hero ... dies permanently in the Marvel Cinematic Universe."

Comment: "The nature of the Avengers is that they're avenging the death of one of the team" Where did you get this? This is patently untrue.

Comment: @BCdotWEB this is not the first time somebody thought about it and Avengers word do means something else then marvel's PG-13 superhero can ever do.

Comment: @BCdotWEB they were literally avenging the death of Phil Coulson in *The Avengers*. His death is the reason they work as a team. So I think his assumption is alright

Comment: @KharoBangdo The Avengers Initiative is first mentioned in the *Iron Man* post-credits scene: http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Post-credits_Scenes . Please explain how that use of "avenge" is related to the death of a character who is still alive in *Iron Man 2* and *Thor*.

Comment: @BCdotWEB This quote is from the IMDB trivia for Avengers Assemble, "Agent Phil Coulson... is killed off in the middle of the film, giving the Avengers someone to avenge."

Comment: @BCdotWEB The *Avengers Initiative* was a govt. sanctioned proposal. It's members were Romanoff, Barton, Coulson(if you follow AoS, you'll know) & Rogers. Stark & Banner were consultants. But in *The Avengers* movie, it is mentioned twice that Avengers Initiative was scrapped, once by Fury to the council & once by Tony to Coulson. "There **was** an idea... Phil Coulson dies still believing in that idea". These group of people work together as a team to avenge the death of Coulson & brand themselves Avengers, which is different from being members of Avengers Initiative (1/2)

Comment: @BCdotWEB These Avengers are independent hence, after Ultron govt. tries to control them through the Sokovia Accords which only Stark, Rodney & Vision agree to sign. Rest are still considered fugitives. The Avengers aren't under any govt. control & certainly not the members of The Avengers Initiative. They are avenging the death of Phil Coulson. Later on, as the answer suggest, they are avenging the general public.

Answer (score 16):

The Avengers aren't called the Avengers because they avenge *each other*. They're called that (at least within the MCU) because they avenge the people of Earth in general. In the first *Avengers* film Tony Stark tells Loki something like this:

> If we can't save the Earth, you can be damn well sure we'll avenge it.

So if they're avenging anyone in *Infinity War*, it's the people Thanos has already killed in his quest for the Infinity Stones, and the people he may yet kill.